# php configuration error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

My php files were working fine but today when i check them i get following errors.

```
Warning: require_once(Connections/deal.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\complete project\ordering system\orderingcart.php on line 1

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Connections/orders.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\complete project\orderingcart.php on line 1
```

I don't know how to resolve these errors, where do I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means, the path you gave in `require_once()` is invalid. You have two options,

1.Checkout whether the path `Connections/deal.php` is correct or not. Do you have a folder `Connections` in the folder where this running file is placed? Is there a `deal.php` inside that folder `Connections`?

I think your running file path is `C:\complete project\ordering system\orderingcart.php`. It does not have such a folder and file. **So place your Connections folder in `C:\complete project\ordering system\` and checkout**.

2.Else, You can run the page without fatal error if you change the line to `include_once(Connections/deal.php)`. Functions assosciated with `deal.php` will be inactivated.

Comment: There id connection folder but inside that folder i didnt find any deal.php

Comment: Thats why the error happens. Place `deal.php` inside the file

Comment: hey that issue is resolved. Now i am stuck into another issue when i try to connect to phpmyadmin to Mysql server it asks username and password. I supply default username and password. it then say the following error had occured "Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly."   how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the file has either moved OR the file permission have been altered as to prevent the server account (usually www-data) from having access to it.

You might also have better luck by trying to access the file by suppling an absolute path, rather than a relative path, e.g:

```
<?php

      $lines = file("C:\\Documents and Settings\\myfile.txt");

      foreach($lines as $line){
         echo($line);
       }

 ?>
```

Comment: where do i supply these path?

Comment: perhaps you can do the following: require_once("C:\\Documents and Settings\\myfile.txt");

Comment: Though, I have to ask... why are you accessing a file outside of your website directory?

Comment: hey that issue is resolved. Now i am stuck into another issue when i try to connect to phpmyadmin to Mysql server it asks username and password. I supply default username and password. it then say the following error had occured "Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly."   how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

This file path issue give full file location like

if it is windows

require_once('C:/complete project/Connections/deal.php');

For reference

http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Comment: hey that issue is resolved. Now i am stuck into another issue when i try to connect to phpmyadmin to Mysql server it asks username and password. I supply default username and password. it then say the following error had occured "Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly."   how to resolve this error?